# Unexpected results when looping through json object

Tags: json, vb.net, parsing, variables, if-statement

I've got a little app which makes a http get call to an api to retrieve resource stats.
I get a JSON response similar to this:

```
    { "listcapacityresponse" : { "count":6 ,"capacity" : [  {"type":6,"zoneid":"f26c2094-f2ca-4951-9265-a3f036e7f045","zonename":" CloudPlatform 1","capacityused":45660766208,"capacitytotal":106308304896,"percentused":"42.95"}, {"type":8,"zoneid":"f26c2094-f2ca-4951-9265-a3f036e7f045","zonename":" CloudPlatform 1","capacityused":5,"capacitytotal":18,"percentused":"27.78"}, {"type":5,"zoneid":"f26c2094-f2ca-4951-9265-a3f036e7f045","zonename":" CloudPlatform 1","capacityused":3,"capacitytotal":12,"percentused":"25"}, {"type":3,"zoneid":"f26c2094-f2ca-4951-9265-a3f036e7f045","zonename":" CloudPlatform 1","capacityused":90202701824,"capacitytotal":1099511627776,"percentused":"8.2"}, {"type":1,"zoneid":"f26c2094-f2ca-4951-9265-a3f036e7f045","zonename":" CloudPlatform 1","capacityused":1500,"capacitytotal":52800,"percentused":"2.84"}, {"type":0,"zoneid":"f26c2094-f2ca-4951-9265-a3f036e7f045","zonename":" CloudPlatform 1","capacityused":1476395008,"capacitytotal":97078222080,"percentused":"1.52"} ] } }
```

Basically, there are 6 types of resource which are:

0 Memory Usage
1 CPU Usage
3 Primary Storage
5 Management IPs
6 Secondary storage
8 Shared Network IPs

I'm parsing the JSON like this:

```
    Dim dtoObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(resourceusageresponse)
        For Each resource As Capacity In dtoObj.listcapacityresponse.capacity

    If resource.type = 0 Then
                Dim memoryusedpercent As String = resource.percentused
            ElseIf resource.type = 1 Then
                Dim cpuusedpercent As String = resource.percentused
            ElseIf resource.type = 3 Then
                Dim pristorageusedpercent As String = resource.percentused
            ElseIf resource.type = 5 Then
                Dim mgmtippercent As String = resource.percentused
            ElseIf resource.type = 6 Then
                Dim secstoragepercent As String = resource.percentused
            ElseIf resource.type = 8 Then
                Dim guestippercent As String = resource.percentused
            End If

        Next
```

I would expect each of the variables within the if statement to be populated once it had finished parsing (i'm only really interested in percent for now), but instead i just get empty variables and no error.

Am i missing something obvious?

Am desperate to get this bit of my project closed off and this is the last thing standing in my way!

any help appriciated! :)

Comment: Your variables will become out of scope outside of the If Statement.  Dim those bad boys before you even start your loop and then you should have values.

Comment: Ahh i see, i meant to change those, however i have the following at the top...

    Public memoryusedpercent As String = ""
    Public cpuusedpercent As String = ""
    Public pristorageusedpercent As String = ""
    Public mgmtippercent As String = ""
    Public secstoragepercent As String = ""
    Public guestippercent As String = ""

So I would have thought that would be enough. 
I'll tidy them up now and try again

Comment: ahhh indeed, once i tidied them up i have the response i am expecting!
Thank you kind sir!

Comment: For anyone who cares, the code stayed the same except the if statement, which became...

        If resource.type = 0 Then
                    memoryusedpercent = resource.percentused
                ElseIf resource.type = 1 Then
                    cpuusedpercent = resource.percentused
                ElseIf resource.type = 3 Then
                    pristorageusedpercent = resource.percentused
                ElseIf resource.type = 5 Then
                    mgmtippercent = resource.percentused
                ElseIf etc.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables will become out of scope outside of the If Statement.  Dim them above the loop and you should be fine.